# Font rendering in wrong color on Chromium

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium

The Google font [Nanum Gothi](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nanum+Gothic)c is rendering in the wrong color on Chromium and Ubuntu. The color renders as expected for other browser and OS combinations. For instance, the font is rendered properly on Chromium and MacOS.

The two images illustrate the problem: for some reason, the checkmark is rendered in gray and not yellow. (The weird spacing is a separate issue.)

We tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and Chromium 80.0.3987.0 (r722234).

Any suggestions what is causing this?

**Correct**

[image]

**Wrong**

[image]

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/Crashalot/pen/9e51b87f9199ae917aeee69ed6dc4866

**HTML**

```
<html><head>
   <link href="/stylesheets/reset.css?1547166062" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Gothic:regular" rel="stylesheet">
<style>


   body {
      background: transparent;
   }


   #designBox {
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      position: absolute;
      background: transparent;
      margin: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
   }


   .itemBox, .itemBox > * {
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }


   .backgroundColorBox, .backgroundGraphicBox, .foregroundBox, .frameBox {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      pointer-events: none;
   }


   .backgroundColorBox.design, .backgroundGraphicBox.design  {
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: auto;
   }


   .backgroundGraphicBox {
      background-position: initial;
      background-repeat: repeat;
   }


   .itemBox.text .ql-editor {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      overflow: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      cursor: text;
   }


   .itemBox.text .foregroundBox * {
      line-height: 1em;
   }


   .itemBox.text p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      caret-color: black;
      pointer-events: initial;
   }


   .itemBox.text p:last-child {
      margin: 0;
   }


   #designBox {
      transform: scale(1.0);
   }
</style></head>


<body><div id="designBox" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;" data-preserve-aspect-ratio="1" data-font-list="Nanum+Gothic:regular">

    <div class="backgroundColorBox design" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div>

<div class="itemBox text" id="MFExztST243v" style="top: 387px; left: 63px; width: 866px; height: 264px;"><div class="foregroundBox ql-container ql-disabled" style="width: 866px; height: 264px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="false" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"><p style="align-self: flex-start;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0em; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; font-size: 72px; color: rgb(255, 193, 7); font-family: &quot;Nanum Gothic&quot;; font-style: normal;">✔Premium web filter and&nbsp;</span></p><p style="align-self: flex-start;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0em; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; font-size: 72px; color: rgb(255, 193, 7); font-family: &quot;Nanum Gothic&quot;; font-style: normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;app blocker included</span></p></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Do you see the same result when Chromium is launched using command line argument: `--force_fieldtrials`?

Comment: Is the typeface installed locally in any of the test cases?

Comment: @killscreenmike good question. no, it's not. any suggestions?

Comment: @Asesh try installing the typeface locally, or using only locally available typefaces and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the problem was that the checkmark was being rendered from the Apple emoji font installed on the server, causing the checkmark to appear in gray.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143

I'll refer you to comment 67 for the possible solution:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143#c67

It appears that fonts hold different IDs which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: hi this wasn't the solution but awarded you the bounty for spending the time to investigate. thanks for your help!

Comment: I appreciate it. Sorry it didn't help!

Comment: maybe it will help someone in the future. :)